# Filemanager for TinyMCE on java platform

Tags: java, file-upload, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE ( http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php ) as an editor on a webproject running on a Java-platform (Tomcat, Spring)
There's a filemanager on the webpage for TinyMCE:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_filemanager.php

But as stated on that page: 
*"The MCFileManager is a online file management utility, available as PHP and .NET"*

So no Java-support it seems.

Does anyone know another filemanager for TinyMCE that works with Java or has another (simple) solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the answer, haven't tried it myself yet though, but it seems to work.

**TinyFCK**

TinyFCK integrates the TinyMCE rich text editor with FCKEditor's file manager and uploader. TinyFCK combines the advantages of TinyMCE's features with a free file manager.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/tinyfck/

**Integrate TinyFCK with JSP**

http://www.jroller.com/coreteam/entry/integrate_tinyfck_with_jsp

Or one might just use the FCKEditor for Java directly
http://java.fckeditor.net/